# Is it possible for someone with juvenile felony charge (not conviction) to join the military?

Tags: united-states, military, criminal-record, juvenile-law

If someone were charged with a felony in the US (e.g. sexual assault, harassment, or murder) as a juvenile, but they're not convicted (their case or the charges were dropped), can they join the military after they turn 18? If not, then why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [US Army](https://m.goarmy.com/learn.m.html)'s web site, which gives an overview of the entry requirements, the minimum age is 17 and it seems that only felony *convictions* and juvenile *offences* are a bar to recruitment - however the Army Recruiter should be able to confirm whether or not dropped charges fall in to these categories or exclude a candidate for any other reason.

**Section 1** "meeting with a recruiter" section includes this:

> Your local recruiter will conduct a prescreening to see if you qualify for enlistment. At the recruiting station, he or she will ask you about your:
>
> - Education level
> - **Criminal history**
> - Age
> - Marital/dependency status
> - Physical condition

And one of the "*see if you pre-qualify*" quick-quiz questions asks if one's age is between 17 and 34

**Section 2**, "required documents", includes this:

> The U.S. Army makes every attempt to assess the moral quality of potential recruits. To this end, a thorough background check is done on all prospects.
>
> - **It is imperative that you disclose all legal offenses**
> - **Felony convictions will result in candidates being exclude**
> - Drug and domestic violence charges will exclude candidates (Some minor drug offenses may be waived on a case-by-case basis)
> - **Juvenile offenses will also exclude you**
> - Certain Army jobs requiring higher security clearance may necessitate more thorough investigations

Comment: Shorter: A non-conviction does not categorically disqualify you. A "juvenile offense" is a form of conviction. It probably requires explanation, however, and might conceivably limit your access to high security clearance jobs if the folks evaluating the background check for a security clearance think that the circumstances of the non-conviction crime cast enough doubt (even though not beyond a reasonable doubt of conviction) on your trustworthiness.